# Processor and motherboard ram frequency support

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

How do i find out what the max ram speed my mother board and processor support? I have a P8H67-M EVO which can be found [here](http://www.asus.com/uk/Motherboards/P8H67M_EVO/) and I also have an i5 2310 which can be found [here](http://ark.intel.com/products/53445/Intel-Core-i5-2310-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_20-GHz).

Answer (score 1):

According to the specifications for your [motherboard](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131710), your board can support DDR3 RAM speeds of 1066 and 1333.

As for your [CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/53445/Intel-Core-i5-2310-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_20-GHz), you can overclock it to 3.2 where it will be stable. Of course, you can always go further than this, but unless you are an experienced OverClocker, I would suggest not overclocking your CPU, unless the auto overclocking BIOS utility allows you to. Overclocking a CPU can be very dangerous if you do not know the right voltages/frequencies and you can fry your CPU/Motherboard.